# What is the real need and concept of average in normal sense (not in form of calculus)? Please see below what I mean by asking this question.

Tags: education, math-history, average, ratio

I know how to calculate average, but never get the idea why we need to do that. For example see a question I did correctly just by following only some steps. I got the correct answer, but don't know why we need to find average speed, average weight (average anything) and how that will be useful to us in real life.
Please see the image in this link: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nK9b.png)

Can anyone answer this in simple maths words and please don't go in to calculus or other level. For example if the weight of 4 boxes are 2,4,6 and 8, then average will be (2+4+6+8)/4 = 20/4 = 5. From my knowledge I can tell out of total 20kg we can divide these in to 4 equal parts with each weighing 5kg. But why we find this value, how this will be useful in a real life scenario. What made mathematician to introduce average and how saying average speed is 30 and average weight is 5kg help ones. Please answer this question even it's seem very simple since most maths textbooks and teachers ever teach why wee need average and they only teach to solve a problem. That's why I got above answer correct but don't know the concept.

Comment: This is not exactly what you're asking, but you might find it useful. Consider the numbers 6, 11, 12, 9, 8. Now let's pick some number (could be a number in the list, doesn't have to be an integer), say 10 for example, and let's look at all the *signed* differences with respect to 10: $10-6,$ $10-11,$ $10-12,$ $10-9,$ $10-8,$ which equal $4,$ $-1,$ $-2,$ $1,$ $2.$ If we add these signed differences, then we get $4.$ It can be shown that there is exactly ONE number whose signed differences with the numbers in our list, when added together, result in $0.$ This number happens to be the average.

Comment: Thanks. I am noticing that property for the first time when you explained it to me.

Comment: I discovered this property as a way to quickly compute my average test scores in high school, and managed to show why it works in general, but I kind of intuitively stumbled on it before I managed to come up with a rigorous and general algebraic proof. Suppose the test grades are 86, 92, 90, 84, 95, 97. Then I'd guess a "nice number" as an approximation for the average, which in this case would probably be 90. Adding the signed differences *from* 90 gives $-4 + 2 + 0 - 6 + 5 + 7 = 4,$ so the numbers add to an "excess of $4$ over $90$", and so I "intuited" that the average would be $90 + 4/6.$

Answer (score 1):

Averages are very useful for comparing sets of data.

For example, if you had a a set of data showing the test scores at one school and then a set of data of data showing the test scores a different school, then the average score of both schools could be directly compared to give an idea about the quality of the school.

The average you have given (called the mean) is only one type of average, there are a few others that are useful in different situations (such as the mode or median: https://www2.le.ac.uk/offices/ld/all-resources/numerical-data/averages

Another example of where the average might be useful is when dealing with rates. Lets say you know one person completes a job in 10 hours and the other one completes it in 2 hours, then their respective average rates are 1/10 and 1/2, so if they were to work together, they would have a rate of 6/10, so can complete the job in $10/6=1.67$ hours